# XSL - Check if select has no text nodes then show "Not Results"

Tags: testing, xslt

How can I check if my block/select has no text nodes then show "Not Results"

```
    <xsl:choose>    
    <xsl:when test="@pass='0' or @pass='1'">
    <fo:block padding-top="1cm" font-weight="bold" margin-bottom="0.2cm">Header</fo:block>                                          <fo:block margin-top="0.2cm" margin-bottom="0.2cm" border-bottom="1px solid #e1e1e1">
</fo:block>
    <fo:block margin-top="0.2cm" margin-bottom="0.2cm" padding-left="5px" padding-right="5px" padding-top="1px">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="detail/katalog/frage[@ko='1' and @passed='0']" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="detail/katalog/frage/options" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="detail/katalog/matrix/frage/options" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="detail/katalog/clusterArea/clusterFrage[@ko='1' and @passed='0']" />
    </fo:block>
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
<xsl:if test="(not(detail/katalog/frage[@ko='1' and @passed='0']) and not(detail/katalog/clusterArea/clusterFrage[@ko='1' and @passed='0']) and not(detail/katalog/frage/options) and not(detail/katalog/matrix/frage/options))">
<fo:block>
Not Results
</fo:block>
 </xsl:if>
```

Thanks a lot!
PR

Comment: Where is input and which context you are now?

Comment: The If condition does not work: 
not(detail/katalog/frage/options) and not(detail/katalog/matrix/frage/options)

Comment: You  need to be precise as to what you mean by "NULL"? Do you mean the element does not exist, or does it exist but has no child elements or text nodes?

Comment: Sorry,  It does exist but has no text nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements you are checking exist, but your current check `detail/katalog/frage[@ko='1' and @passed='0']` for example will return true, as that is just checking for the existence of the element itself, regardless of whether it has child nodes or not

So, you want to do something like this....

```
not(detail/katalog/frage[@ko='1' and @passed='0']/text())
```

However, you also need to watch out for whitespace only nodes, so you might want to augment the check like so...

```
not(detail/katalog/frage[@ko='1' and @passed='0']/text()[normalize-space()])
```

Alternatively, you could strip out whitespace only nodes by using `xsl:strip-space`

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
```